# Finding longs across different formats

Tags: vba, excel

I have data that's in multiple formats and I am struggling to change them in an attempt to locate them.  The numbers in question are currently stored as numbers in the format `dataT.Range("F2:F" & lRow).NumberFormat = "###.00"` However they are stored elsewhere in another spreadsheet as #### with the decimal not being included.  Examples of this would be original format: "30.00"  New format "3000" or Original format: "10.50" New format "1050".  I attempted to remove the decimal through the `Replace()` Function, but I was fairly certain it would fail and it did.  Any thoughts or recommendations would be much appreciated.  This function is a very tiny piece of a larger routine.

**Question put Simply: I need to change numbers stored in this format "30.00" to target format "3000"  Line with the starts to the right is where I attempted to fix the problem**

```
Function AnalyzeOiData(lRow As Integer, oiDataSheet As Worksheet, productSheet As Worksheet, rownum As Integer)

Dim counter As Integer
Dim monthExp As String
Dim oiLocationFinder As Range
Dim strikeLoc As Range
Dim optStrike As Long

For counter = rownum To lRow

     'Returns formatted monthcode for finding the different months of expiry embedded in the OI data
     monthExp = GetMonthCode(productSheet.Cells(counter, 1), productSheet.Cells(counter, 2))
     optStrike = Replace(productSheet.Cells(counter, 3), ".", "")  ***
     oiLocationFinder = oiDataSheet.Columns(1).Find(monthExp)

     oiLocationFinder.Select
     strikeLoc = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Find(optStrike).Address

     productSheet.Cells(counter, 11) = strikeLoc.Offset(0, 9)
     productSheet.Cells(counter, 12) = strikeLoc.Offset(0, 10)

Next

End Function
```

Comment: `10.50 * 100 = 1050` ?

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code in your post, thanks :)

Comment: Just went to do that and Scott did it.  Apologies it got thrown off when I copied it over.

Comment: I could use Alex K's solution, but is that a bit ghetto? Or is that the simplest most useful solution.

Comment: It depends. Is it guaranteed that values containing a decimal point will contain 2 decimal places? And if so, do you want every one of these values to be multiplied by 100?

Comment: Yes, in this circumstance I suppose it is. Though if it changes I could use a case statement to differentiate the differences for them if necessary.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Input each cell that you are processing into the following sub:

```
Sub Convert(cell As Range)
    If cell.NumberFormat = "0.00" Then
        cell.Value = cell.Value * 100
        cell.NumberFormat = "0"
    End If
End Sub
```

If you feed these cells in...

[image: Original data]

...the result is:

[image: Processed data]

Answer (score 1):

You can run an efficient search with `Find` rather than look at each cell:

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "0.00"

Set rng1 = Range("A1:A10").Find("*", , , , , , , , True)
Do While Not rng1 Is Nothing
    rng1.Value2 = rng1.Value2 * 100
    rng1.NumberFormat = "0"
    Set rng1 = Range("A1:A10").Find("*", , , , , , , , True)
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

To broaden the "multiply by 100" answers into something more general, the below code will look to see how many decimal places there are, then multiply by the correct factor of 10 to remove the decimals.

```
Dim iDec as Integer
If Instr(1,productSheet.Cells(counter,3),".") > 0 Then
    iDec = Len(productSheet.Cells(counter,3))-Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(".",productSheet.Cells(counter,3))
    productSheet.Cells(counter,3) = productSheet.Cells(counter,3) * (10^iDec)
End If
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm not 100% certain and am not anywhere that I can test right now,  but would

> Range ("F2").Value2 * 100

work here?   It should give the underlying value without formatting,  no?

Comment: For an input of "30.00", this will give "30", not "3000" as requested.